# Windows 7: Windows randomly become "always on top"

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, always-on-top

Kind of a weird issue: Often while I'm using Windows 7 with multiple app windows, one or more of them will randomly become "always on top", not allowing me to access my taskbar below (it's set to auto-hide). Anyone know why this happens?

Comment: What resolves it? Its not some aero-peek oddity / curser issue is it?

Comment: It seems to resolve itself randomly as well. I have Aero disabled.

Comment: Multiple screens or app windows?

Comment: @Karan Not really sure what you mean.

Comment: You said while you're using Win7 with multiple screens one or more will randomly become always on top. Sounds strange to me, how do screens and not app windows become always on top? That's why I asked you for clarification.

Comment: Alright, app windows then.